# Variable JSP doesn't get input text value in HTML

Tags: html, jsp

I have in HTML code:

`<input type="text" name="addd" value="0">`

Then my Java code:

```
    <%
    int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("addd")); 
    %>
```

I want the variable contb in JSP to get the value of the HTML textbox named "addd" but it gives an Exception. Can you help me?

Comment: Please include the exception that you are getting in the question?

Comment: where is your jsp code ? how do you submit or send your input values to jsp code? what exception do you got ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="addd" value="0">
```

Setting `value` to `"0"` makes it a string. Remove the quotes to have the value be a number.

```
<input type="text" name="addd" value=0>
```

If you only want numbers in your input, you can use

```
<input type="number" name="addd" min="10" max="100">
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) for more about that.

You also asked why you could not use html tags in your post. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more about that.

Comment: Ok, but how will the JPS variable receive of the textbox value in HTML? It must be an Integer. ```` <h2>Variable for List:</h2><input type="number" name="addd" value=0 id="ad3" min="0" max="20"><br>
 <%
 int cont = 0;
 int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ad3"));
 //contb = 6;
 %> ````

Comment: Try using: `int contb = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("addd"));`  Notice that I am referencing the `name` attribute as opposed to the `id`.

Comment: Actually the HTML input="text" had to be in a <form  /form> with a submit button. It works now. Thks.